'str' object is not callable error in Python/Selenium web-scraping script
I have a very simple Python/Selenium web-scraping script, as follows:
from re import L
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

cService = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Frank\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2022\\Projects\\IV3_WebsiteAutomation\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = cService)
driver.get("https://app.iv3.us/login")
print(driver.title)

search_bar = driver.find_element("name", "userName")
search_bar.send_keys("paynterf@gmail.com")
search_bar = driver.find_element("name", "password")
search_bar.send_keys("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# res = driver.find_element(By.XPATH(".//a[contains(@href,'View Active')]"))
# res = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//a[contains(@href,'View Active')]"))
XXX = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//div[./h4[text()='Moved from Registered Address']]//a[text()='View Active']"))

driver.close() 

When run, the 'XXX = driver.find_element...' line produces the dreaded 'str' object is not callable error.
Googling the error has led me to numerous posts describing how this error is caused by attempting to use a Python reserved word for a variable, but I can't see how that could be happening in my script; I even went so far as to change the 'res' variable name to 'XXX', but this didn't change anything.
Could it be that this line:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

and its subsequent use in the last line of the script is causing the problem?   I got this usage from the Selenium 'Locating Elements' tutorial , so I would be amazed if it was the issue, but....
TIA,
Frank
[edit]: per request from @OneCricketeer, I have included the error traceback:
IV3 'str' object is not callable Stack trace: > File "C:\Users\Frank\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\IV3_WebsiteAutomation\IV3_WebsiteAutomation.py", line 20, in <module> (Current frame) > XXX = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//div[./h4[text()='Moved from Registered Address']]//a[text()='View Active']")) >TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Loaded 'main' Loaded 'runpy'


Please show your complete traceback

IV3
'str' object is not callable
Stack trace:

File "C:\Users\Frank\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\IV3_WebsiteAutomation\IV3_WebsiteAutomation.py", line 20, in  (Current frame)
XXX = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//div[./h4[text()='Moved from Registered Address']]//a[text()='View Active']"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Loaded 'main'
Loaded 'runpy'


Whenever you post important info (like the error message above), you should always edit it into your question. If you are responding to someone, message them using @ in the comments letting them know you added X to your question.

This line is not correct syntax.
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//div[./h4[text()='Moved from Registered Address']]//a[text()='View Active']"))

It should be in the form
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "...")

To see more clearly
driver.find_element(By.XPATH("...")) # incorrect
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "...") # correct

To update your code,
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[./h4[text()='Moved from Registered Address']]//a[text()='View Active']")


Progress!!  The 'find_element' function still failed, but now it fails with "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[./h4[text()='Moved from Registered Address']]//a[text()='View Active']"}".

Thanks - that did the trick.  The 'no such element' issue was fixed by adding 'driver.implicitly_wait(2)' at the top of the script.
